# Deducing asymptotically stability if $|f(x)| <|x|$

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

let f be a continuous map such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(x)|<|x|$ whenever $0<|x|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$>0

a) show that the sequence $f^{n}(x)$ has a limit point $x_{*}$

b) show that $|f(x_{*})|=|x_{*}|$

c) Deduce that $x{*}=0$, and hence that 0 is an asymptotically stable fixed point.

Does anyone know how to do this or have any idea on how to start?

Comment: I take it $f^n=f\circ \dots \circ f$?

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry for not defining that.

Comment: Are you assuming in $(a)$ that $x\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$?

Comment: I'm not too sure sorry.

Comment: Consider the function $x\mapsto x^2$. Then it is continuous and $|x^2|<|x|$ over $(-1,1)$, however, choosing some initial $x$ on $\Bbb R\setminus [-1,1]$ gives no convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints (which only show that $0$ is locally asymptotically stable with region of attraction $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$):

Suppose that $\bar{x}\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and consider the sequences $a_1:=\bar{x}$, $a_{n+1}:=f(a_n)$ and $b_n:=|a_n|$. A monotonically decreasing sequence converges if and only if it is bounded. Show that $(b_n)$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded and conclude that $b_n\rightarrow b_*$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Show that $b_*\in[0,\varepsilon)$ (use monotonicity of $(b_n)$ and the fact that a convergent sequence in a closed set converges inside the set).

Use the [sequence definition of a continuous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences) and $(b_n)$ to show that $f(b_*)=b_*$.

Using the above and the fact that $|f(x)|<|x|$ if $x\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, argue by contradiction that $b_*=0$. What does this imply about $a_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

I think that pretty much does it (unless I messed up somewhere). Let me know if you want me to flesh the whole solution out in detail. Also note that the above proves $b)\Rightarrow c)\Rightarrow a)$ - I couldn't think of way to start by proving $a)$ first...

Comment: Thanks for this. Would $b_{n}$ be bounded above by $|f(a_{n-1})|$? How do we actually show that $b_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing?

Comment: First notice that by definition $b_n\geq0$. Then, the sequence $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing if and only if for all $n$, $b_{n+1}\leq b_n$. You can show this by induction. Suppose that $b_n=|a_n|\in[0,\varepsilon)$, then $a_n\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and thus $0\leq b_{n+1} = |a_{n+1}| = |f(a_n)|< |a_n|=b_n< \varepsilon$. So $b_{n+1}\in[0,\varepsilon)$ and $b_{n+1}\leq b_n$. The base case is then given by $b_1=|a_1|=\bar{x}\in[0,\varepsilon)$. Notice that we have also shown that $(b_n)$ is bounded by showing that all its elements are contained in the bounded interval $[0,\varepsilon)$